# When did Poe run spice?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker, poe-dameron

In *The Rise of Skywalker*, it's said that Poe was a spice runner at some point in the past.  When exactly was this?  His parents were both original members of the Rebellion; when did he slip out to sell drugs?  Is this in the *Freefall* book?  The movie made it seem like this was an extended period of his life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*Rise of Skywalker Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary) gives us a timeline of Poe's life prior to the film series. He was born in 32BSI (2ABY) and spent 5 years (between the ages of 16 and 21) working as a spice runner and living as a general *ne'er-do-well* on Kijimi.

> Poe rebelled during his adventure-seeking teenage years when his
> father, an Alliance veteran named Kes, attempted to instil some
> responsibility in him. Poe ran away from his home on Yavin 4  and fell
> in with the wrong crowd — specifically, the Spice Runners of Kijimi.
> These dangerous criminals would have killed Poe had he not proven to
> be an amazing pilot. After a career as a young pirate and smuggler,
> Poe returned to his familial home to find that all would be forgiven
> if he forged a straighter path. Poe then began his service in the New
> Republic, and later joined the Resistance.

[image]

Note that this timeline breaks Poe's previously known (and supposedly canon) back-story from [*Age of Resistance #1 - Poe Dameron*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_Resistance_-_Poe_Dameron_1).

Some attempt was made to fix the problem by detailing his younger life in [*Poe Dameron: Free Fall*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Poe_Dameron:_Free_Fall) (explaining how and why he left Yavin at such a young age), but since neither story has been decanonised, we're left with a clash that Lucasfilm don't seem particularly interested in resolving.